# How to change the default opening page to a component other than AppComponent?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an Angular 6 application. At first it was just one page (let's say "search page"), so I put the page content in
app.component.html and related functions, etc. to the app.component.ts. So the search page is in appcomponent.
Now I was asked to add another page (Login page). So, now the first page that needs to be opened when
the page is first loaded is login page. If the login is successful, then "search page" should open.

I am new to Angular so I look at some routing & navigation tutorials and applied what they are doing.
The problem is that now when the page is first loaded it opens both LoginComponent and AppComponent (search page) together.
At the top of the page login screen and under that search screen. Also, if I go to "/search" then this time
there is two search pages one under the other.

So I have one extra search page.I get that the problem is that the search page is being in appcomponent.
I guess that the app loads this component by default. What I want is that I want to display LoginComponent
first (when the page is first loaded), if the login is successful, navigate to search page.

Here is what I have done to add routing:

1. I added `import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';` to my **app.module.ts**
2. Also I added RouterModule in imports like this (again in **app.module.ts**)

   ```
   imports: [

       RouterModule.forRoot([
         {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
         {path: 'search', component:AppComponent}

       ])
   ],
   ```
3. Added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in **app.component.html**. This HTML file included my search page content like navbar, table etc. And at the beginning of it I put router line (I know it is wrong to put inside my search page but In the tutorial I watched, he put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html. I guess that the reason for my double pages is this HTML file but could not get it to work somewhere else.)
4. In **login.component.html**,
   Login page content and of course a Login button with (click)="onLogin()"
5. **login.component.ts** includes onLogin function if the login is successful `this.router.navigate(['/search']);`
6. Finally in my index.html I call the appcomponent inside body `<app-root></app-root>`

Right now navigation with login works but as I said the initial page with URL: "http://localhost:4200/"
includes both login and search page. Also URL: "http://localhost:4200/search" includes two search pages.

Comment: the `router-outlet` is in your AppComponent, and you have route that redirects to AppComponent as well? what are you trying to do..?

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake. I am trying to understand/learn. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

Just create a new component for `search` and remove it from `app` component, then change your route module to

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
])
```

And make sure that in `app.component.html`, only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` exists

Comment: How can I do the same for other module.

Comment: @Santosh create a new route in your other module with a new path, which will point to the component that you want

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct, just remove the search component from app.component html and have only login component.

You can use the Routing mechanism with authguard to navigate to search page once the login is successful

Comment: Hello, as I understand correctly, you think that I have 3 components; search, login and app. I actually have two. LoginComponent and AppComponent. The search page div's are in app.component.html. I know I should have created a separate component for search but it is too late for that :) So if I remove search content from AppComponent there will be no search page :) But if you are saying there is no other way, I will create a new component for search. Thank you!

Comment: Since the first plan was to have only search page, I put everything in AppComponent at first. But now I added LoginComponent

Comment: yes separating the component would give what you wanted

Comment: @Artyom yes the downvote is because of that i guess. When you post duplicate answers it happens. It happened for me many times

Answer (score 2):

You can try redirect.

Refer the official docs: [angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial)

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
{path: '', redirectTo: '/component-name', pathMatch: 'full'},
]),
],
```

Comment: This works well if you have some sort of auth interceptor. Using the method above didn't work and my auth redirect would just hang.